# Buffered FIFO queue for streaming bytes in python?

Tags: python, node.js

I am doing a lot of processing and generating of csv and json files in python, to which I'm new-ish. Here's a typical example of what I have done so far:

```
# return a db cursor that streaming rows of data
row_iter = await get_row_iterator() 
# get a pointer to a google cloud storage object to store the csv
gcs_object = self.gcs_client.bucket(self.env.temp_bucket).blob(manifest_key)

with gcs_object.open(mode="w", content_type="text/csv") as f:
    async for row_obj in row_iter:
        f.write(f"{row_obj.some_column},{row_obj.some_other_column}\n")
```

This works fine, but if I understand correctly, the problem is that there is a lot of waiting around. While I'm writing a row with `f.write()`, the row-reading iterator `row_iter` is just sitting there doing nothing. While I'm reading from the iterator, the writer is twiddling its thumbs. While the way I've done this conserves memory, from a speed perspective its no better than reading all the rows into memory first, processing them, and *then* starting an upload. There should be no reason I can't be uploading data that has already been processed while also downloading and processing the next item or batch of items.

I'd like to stream this process, so that the row iterator can be reading rows and stuffing them into a fixed size FIFO buffer as fast as it possibly can, while on the other end I'm reading from the buffer and writing the csv to Google Cloud Storage (or S3, or a local file, etc) as fast as the network can handle. If the buffer fills up, writing to it should block until there is space. If the buffer empties, reading from it should block until there is enough to read so that the maximum amount of memory used by this pipeline is controlled.

Essentially, I want an equivalent to [NodeJS's concept of streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in python. It looks an awful lot like I should be able to do something like this with python's [Buffered Streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#buffered-streams), but I can't figure out how to use them to accomplish this, and I can't find any examples of how they should be used. I'll need to do this with csv, json, and probably other custom formats, so I'm not necessarily looking for a package that handles this for a specific format, but a more generic way, even a way to write my own custom streaming transforms and pipelines.

Comment: In a lot of contexts -- if you're writing to a regular file, f/e -- you get buffering automagically until/unless you go out of your way, as by using `flush()`, to prevent that. What exactly is GCS?

Comment: One way is to create two (or more) threads and connect them with a `queue.Queue` as a buffer. In this case the buffer would have a fixed size of rows instead of a fixed size of bytes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I wasn't clear on that. I'm writing the csv to an object in a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Comment: @MichaelButscher I saw queue.Queue, but that doesn't really look like its designed to process streams of bytes. It can only write one item at a time, and read one item at a time. I should be able to write and read arbitrary sized chunks of bytes at a time, like the streams in Nodejs: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html